# Angular button redirect

Tags: html, css, angular

on the following picture you can see my problem. When i click on the letters of the Edit button i get redirected to the page, otherwise if i click the button but not the letters, it wont do anything. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2UHup.jpg)

this is the code:

```
`<ng-template #ownerTemplate>
    <button class="edit-btn" mat-raised-button><a routerLink="edit">Edit</a></button>
    <button mat-raised-button (click)="deleteMovie(this.movie!._id)">
      Delete
    </button>
  </ng-template>`
```

How can i fix it?

Comment: can you explain more what do you need?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting the routerLink="edit" inside the button and not inside 
Like this :

```
<button class="edit-btn" mat-raised-button routerLink="edit"><a>Edit</a></button>
  <button mat-raised-button >
    Delete
  </button>
```

You can also remove the <a> if you dont use it